# Is there a way to use different pattern for different packages when using log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I'm using log4j (through slf4j) and I'd like logs from some packages to output filename and line numbers but for others I just need the level and the message. Is there a way to achieve this? Is it possible to specific different layout.ConversionPattern for different classes/packages using the log4j2.properties file?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? You should be able to have multiple layouts and assign to different package names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more than one appender of the same type:

Here is an example:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleA" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout pattern=="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
    </Console>
    <Console name="ConsoleB" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout pattern=="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
   </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
   <Logger name="com.foo.BarA" level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleA"/>
   </Logger>
   <Logger name="com.foo.BarB" level="trace">
     <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleB"/>
   </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Read more at [Log4J configuration manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)